# How can I make a Promise resolve only after recursion is completed?

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise

I'm having an issue getting this logic to work, and I don't even know if it's possible or if I'm correctly using promises here.

I have this first function that takes in a list of ID's that are used to make a request to pull in specific async data. I can only pull in 1000 at a time, so if the list contains more than 1000, I have to recurse through it.

What I'm looking for is this - For each option that you need to recurse, call the recursive function, **await** the results and then push them to a list. When all the data is obtained, respond with the data.

```
async function getData () {
    .... 
    // Inside condition that determines it needs to recurse
    let _data = await _getOptions(id, data, 0);
    dataList.push(_data);
    ...
    // Eventually, return the data
    res.json(dataList);
}
```

This function recurses through the list and is supposed to resolve once all the data is pulled in.

```
let rData = [];
function _getOptions(id, data, offset) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (data.length < 1000) {
            return resolve(rData);
        }
        let fields = { fields: `id, key_value, label, condition_value`, offset: offset, limit: 1000 };
        options.getOptionsWithFilter(id, fields, (err, data) => {
            rData.push(data);
            _getOptions(id, data, offset + 1000);
        });
    });
}
```

It doesn't seem that this is working because of an error thrown in the console, that would suggest to me it's returning `undefined`. I would guess the issue is that I'm using promises wrong here. But I've been struggling to come up with another solution. I need all the data to be returned in the `_data` variable before I can move on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your promise constructor callback should always result in a call to `resolve` (or `reject`), but when you go on to make the recursive call, you don't ever call `resolve` on *that particular* promise. So call it, like this:

```
resolve(_getOptions(id, data, offset + 1000));
```

I also think your way of combining the chunks of result data is wrong: you would push arrays as nested arrays into the final array. I would expect you would need to concatenate the chunks into a 1 dimensional array.

There is an issue with the use of the `data` variable: you use it for something that is passed to the `_getOptions` function (not sure what that initially is), but also for the *provided* from `getOptionsWithFilter`. I think that latter data is in fact the only `data` you are dealing with. So then you don't need to pass it to `_getOptions`.

It would also be advisable to avoid the use of a global `rData` variable. As you only set it to the empty array once, you risk to not have cleared it for any next request you want to make.

Instead let the final promise yield the final chunk of data and then prepend the previous chunks to it:

```
function _getOptions(id, offset = 0) { // No data argument!
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let fields = { fields: `id, key_value, label, condition_value`, 
                       offset: offset, limit: 1000 };
        options.getOptionsWithFilter(id, fields, (err, data) => {
            if (data.length < 1000) { // Perform the check when you have the data
                return resolve(data); // just this chunk
            }
            resolve(_getOptions(id, offset + 1000) // Don't pass data
                       // prepend this data to the data that the recursive 
                       // promise will provide
                       .then(rData => data.concat(rData))
            );
        });
    });
}
```

You call it like this:

```
_data = await _getOptions(id);
```

#### Alternative: one Promise

You could also choose to perform the asynchronous loop ("recursive call") inside one Promise constructor callback:

```
function _getOptions(id) { // No data argument!
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let rData = [];
        (function loop(offset) {
            let fields = { fields: `id, key_value, label, condition_value`, 
                           offset: offset, limit: 1000 };
            options.getOptionsWithFilter(id, fields, (err, data) => {
                rData = rData.concat(data);
                if (data.length < 1000) { // Perform the check when you have the data
                    return resolve(rData); // All retrieved data
                }
                loop(offset + 1000); // Collect more
            });
        })(0); // Call immediately
    });
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the advice. I will give this solution a try.

Comment: I just amended my answer, as there was also another issue to deal with: the strange use of `data` as input, while it really is output.

Comment: But why is it needed to do 1000 promises to do one batch? WOuldn't it be better to make a helper to do the recursion that resolved one promise?

Comment: True, that would work just as well. I just went with the way the OP had done it. It is not really wrong, just different.

Comment: It would maybe be slightly more performant, but you'd have to juggle with function calls passing on `resolve`, or not? I think this is a very good alternative.

Comment: Performance in such asynchronous code is often close to irrelevant, as most time will go into the work done by `getOptionsWithFilter`.

Comment: NB: I added the one-promise solution to the answer.